# Font render problem makes some programs unusable

Tags: 16.04, fonts

This is from Android Studio SDK running Xenial:

[image]

Notice the very tall text boxes, the lack of spaces in some fonts and others not showing up at all. I've seen this for several proprietary applications. I'm not sure how to diagnose and fix this.

Also some screens on Chrome. Note the lack of digits.

[image]

Comment: Do you remember what you did right before this started happening? Maybe a command that caused this? That would give us a start.

Comment: It *might* have been when I upgraded from 14.04LTS to 16.04LTS. But this only shows in proprietary software. All open-source software works as expected. This problem only occurs in things like Perforce, IntelliJ and other non-open software.

Comment: Chrome also does it. I added a screenshot. But webpages never to do that. I have not tried Chromium.